# How do i assign pointer value inside array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, gcc

i have this error:

ID3.c:71:53: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_object’ {aka ‘struct object’} from type ‘t_object *’ {aka ‘struct object *’}
71 |                 (objects->v[sizeof(void *) * i]) =  t_object_ctor();
|                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

i tried this:

&(objects->v[sizeof(void *) * i]) =  t_object_ctor();

and tried this

*(objects->v[sizeof(void *) * i]) =  t_object_ctor();

and this gives the same error

*((objects->v)+[sizeof(void *) * i]) =  t_object_ctor();

this is the funcion the error is in:
t_objects *t_objects_ctor(){
t_objects *objects =malloc(sizeof(t_objects));

```
    objects->size = 0;
    objects->y = 0;
    objects->x = 0;
    objects->x_size= malloc(sizeof(size_t) * RESONABLENUMBER);
    objects->v= malloc(sizeof(void *) * RESONABLENUMBER);
    for (int i = 0; i < RESONABLENUMBER; ++i) {
        *((objects->v) + sizeof(void *) * i) = t_object_ctor();
    }
    objects->b_size = 0;
    objects->b = NULL;
    
    return objects;
}
```

this is the function im assigning pointers from:

```
t_object *t_object_ctor(){
    t_object *object =malloc(sizeof(t_object));
    
    object->s = 0;
    object->x = NULL;
    object->y = 0;
    
    return object;
    
}
```

Comment: if `objects` is `t_object * objects[]` then it should just be `objects[i] = t_object_ctor();`

Comment: objects is not t_object

Comment: can you post a full code example?

Comment: objects is a pointer on struct that is named t_objects with 'v' that is a pointer to t_object (which i want to use as a array)

Comment: i dont quite understand what you mean by full code example

Comment: Okay, you should be able to do `objects->v[i] = t_object_ctor();` in the `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Try this:

```
((t_object **)objects->v)[i] = t_object_ctor();
```

###### Full code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RESONABLENUMBER 16
typedef struct t_objects {
    int size;
    int x, y;
    void *x_size;
    void *v;
    int b_size;
    char *b;
} t_objects;

typedef struct t_object {
    int s;
    void *x;
    int y;
} t_object;

t_object *t_object_ctor()
{
    t_object *object = malloc(sizeof(t_object));

    object->s = 0;
    object->x = NULL;
    object->y = 0;

    return object;
}

t_objects *t_objects_ctor()
{
    t_objects *objects = malloc(sizeof(t_objects));

    objects->size = 0;
    objects->y = 0;
    objects->x = 0;
    objects->x_size = malloc(sizeof(size_t) * RESONABLENUMBER);
    objects->v = malloc(sizeof(void *) * RESONABLENUMBER);
    for (int i = 0; i < RESONABLENUMBER; ++i) {
        ((t_object **)objects->v)[i] = t_object_ctor();
    }
    objects->b_size = 0;
    objects->b = NULL;

    return objects;
}

int main()
{
    t_objects_ctor();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you declare `void* v` as `t_object** v` you wouldn't need to make the big cast in the for-loop

Comment: this seems to work as i intended, thanks

Comment: if i declare t_object* v as t_object** v it does break and does not compile